# How do I prevent the brush color using a gradient in the weights?

Tags: weight-painting

Good day. I cannot figure out how to draw weight without gradient. In the example below, you can see that the brush only paints red, while mine always paints with a gradient. How can I do applying weights without gradient? Is this a specific setting of the stroke method ?

example
[image]

my brush

[image]

Comment: is your first screenshot from Blender? Because I may be wrong but I think you'll always see a gradient between the vertex that will have 100 weight (red) or whatever wheight) and the next one that will have zero weight

Comment: Yes, first screenshot from blender. There person uses 2.79 version, that's why i want to know how to make it like that. 
i can give you link to the video, but i don't know if I can attach them here

Comment: Yes I've tested in 2.79 and it looks like it was the former display mode, there was no gradient (other than red or whatever color) between a vertex and another, but the fact is that the weights will be the same in 2.8 or 2.9

Comment: @moonboots Is it possible to get same result in the new version?

Comment: I don't see any option in the Viewport Overlays panel, but anyway it doesn't change anything in the way it works, the gradient is not the same but the weight of the next vertex will be 0 like in the 2.79

Answer (score 1):

So from what I see, since 2.8, there's a difference in the way the weight painting gradient is displayed. In 2.79, if you have a vertex that has a weight of 1 and the next one that has a weight of 0, there will be a red to blue gradient (here with a simple non-subdivided cube):

[image]

Since 2.8 you have a red to blue gradient but with all the yellow and green nuances. But it doesn't change anything, the weight of the vertex on the left is still 1 and the weight of the vertex on the right is still 0:

[image]

Comment: thanks, your comment is very informative. But I'm still wondering if there is a way to achieve the same visual display as in the old version - since I find it the most correct for displaying weights. So I will hope someone will find a solution

Comment: I don't find anything in the Preferences but yes, maybe there's a way to switch to the previous mode

Comment: I tried changing variables in preferences-editing-weight paint- use custom color, but that didn't give desired result